# Second button object overwrites the first (Processing)

Tags: java, button, processing

[image]Hej!

I am new in processing, so I am sorry on behalf if Im not clear enough in my questions.

I am making a sort of toaster, that has to start when clicking on a start button and eject bread when you click on the stop button. I have made a button class, and made a new button object in my main program. For testing I made the background color change from white to red when clicking on the start button.

The start button works, but now I am trying to make a new button object (the STOP button), but when I make a stop button object it overwrites the Start button object). First I though it might be because they start button was places underneath the stop button, but thats not it. It also takes forever for the image to load, once I processing.

I hope you can help me :)

```
  int s = 0; 
  int m = 0; 


  Button stop_button;
  Button on_button;
  int clk = 1;



  void setup() 
  {
      on_button = new Button("Start", 230, 300, 60, 30);
      stop_button = new Button("Start", 230, 300, 60, 30);
      size(600, 600);
      background(255, 255, 255);


  }


  void draw () {
    stroke(240, 242, 179);    
    fill(240, 242, 179);
    rect(190,150,210,130, 30);

    stroke(126, 191, 167);
    fill(126, 191, 167);
    rect(170,200,250,170, 30); 



//BUTTON CODE
    if (on_button.MouseIsOver()) {
    }
    on_button.Draw();
  }


  void mousePressed()
  {
    if (on_button.MouseIsOver()) 
      print("Clicked: ");
      println(clk++);
      time(); 
    }

  }

  void time () 
  {
     background(255, 0, 0); 

  }
```

//BUTTON CLASS

```
class Button {
  String label; // button label
  float x;      // top left corner x position
  float y;      // top left corner y position
  float w;      // width of button
  float h;      // height of button

  // constructor
  Button(String labelB, float xpos, float ypos, float widthB, float heightB) {
    label = labelB;
    x = xpos;
    y = ypos;
    w = widthB;
    h = heightB;
  }

  void Draw() {
    fill(218);
    stroke(141);
    rect(x, y, w, h, 10);
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
    fill(0);
    text(label, x + (w / 2), y + (h / 2));
  }

  boolean MouseIsOver() {
    if (mouseX > x && mouseX < (x + w) && mouseY > y && mouseY < (y + h)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't totally understand your code, because you're never reacting to clicks, and you're never drawing the second button.

If I were you, I would [break your problem down into smaller steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and take those steps on one at a time. For example, can you just get a very basic example running that shows a single button that prints a message to the console whenever you click it?

From there, maybe add a second button **in a different location** that prints a different message when you click it. Get that working perfectly before you move on.

When you get that working, then change your first sketch to do something like change the background color when you click the button. Finally, you can combine all of the above to show second button after you click the first button.

Hint: you probably want to use `boolean` variables to represent which button is currently showing. But like I said, your best bet is to start simpler and work your way forward in smaller steps.

Comment: The only thing I have done so far is draw a toaster, and a start button. When you click the button it cals a function called void time, the background turns red - I only did this to test whether it was working. I really want it to start a timer when the void time function is called. But I wanted to start slow, and just see if I could make it do something.... My problem right now is that I need another button next to stat button that says stop, because I need to be able to start and stop the toaster.

Comment: I've attached a picture of the toaster that I have made so far.

Comment: Okay I solved it :D Thanks for feedback though Kevin :)